# lxml not properly parsing tags with multiple classes

Tags: python, lxml

I am trying to parse HTML using

```
a = lxml.html.fromstring('<html><body><span class="cut cross">Text of double class</span><span class="cross">Text of single class</span></body></html>')
s1 = a.xpath('.//span[@class="cross"]')
s2 = a.xpath('.//span[@class="cut cross"]')
s3 = a.xpath('.//span[@class="cut"]')
```

Output:

```
s1 => [<Element span at 0x7f0a6807a530>]
s2 => [<Element span at 0x7f0a6807a590>]
s3 => []
```

But the first span tag has class 'cut', yet s3 is empty. While in s2, when I give both classes, it returns the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the cut2 issues brought up by Scharron, you can concat spaces to the front and end of the class.

```
a.xpath('.//span[contains(concat(" ", @class, " "), " cut ")]')
```

Comment: Will this match if the tag is just `<span class="cut">` ?

Comment: it will. In the above example, it will become `a.xpath('.//span[contains(" cut ", " cut ")]')` which will be true

Answer (score 8):

XPaths equal operator matches exactly the right and left operands.
If you want to search for one of the class, you can use the `contains` function :

```
a.xpath('.//span[contains(@class, "cut")]')
```

However, it can also matches a class like `cut2`.

[cssselect](http://packages.python.org/cssselect/) is a library that handles CSS selectors. A wrapper named [pyquery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery) mimics the JQuery library in python.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the CSS data model (i.e. classes are space-separated values in a single `class` attribute) isn't adhered to for XPath queries. In order to do what you want, you should look at using CSS selectors (for example, via [cssselect](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html)).